# ERRNO::ENOENT: No such file or directory @rb_sysopen - sass/app.sass

Tags: css, sass, smacss

So I am using Atom, but when I use my Atom live-server, the css styles do not apply, in fact I get an error

```
ERRNO::ENOENT: No such file or directory @rb_sysopen - sass/app.sass
```

Should I not be using Atom live-server?

This is the command I am using in the terminal:

```
sass --watch sass:css
```

This is my file structure:

[image]

Comment: I`m not sure, that app.sass located in sass/app.sass

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, what are you telling me?

Comment: maybe try write instead `sass/app.sass` => `./app.sass`

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, so what would that look like in the command line terminal? This is not working -> `sass --watch sass:css`

Answer (score 0):

You should be located in the `SassStructure` folder.
Like this:

```
../SassStructure $ sass --watch sass:css
```

`sass:css` is a reference to both folders: `sass`, and `css`.